# Show that $\DeclareMathOperator{im}{Im} \im(\alpha) \cap \im(\beta)={0_v}=\ker(\alpha) \cap \ker(\beta)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am just completely stuck on this problem, it may just be me confusing the vocabulary and what they mean

Question:

Let V be a finite-dimensional vector space over a field F and let $\alpha, \beta$ be an element of $Hom(V,V)$ be linear transformations satisfying 
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{im}{Im}
\im(\alpha)+\im(\beta)=V=\ker(\alpha)+\ker(\beta).$$
Show that $$\im(\alpha)\cap \im(\beta)={0_v}=\ker(\alpha) \cap \ker(\beta)$$

So I can suppose $\im(\alpha)+\im(\beta)=V=\ker(\alpha)+\ker(\beta)$ to show $\im(\alpha) \cap \im(\beta)={0_v}$

There is a proposition that says $\dim(V)=\dim(\im(\alpha))+\dim(\ker(\alpha))$. I believe I can use this somehow to state $\im(\alpha) \cap \im(\beta)={0_v} ) \Leftrightarrow \dim(\im(\alpha)\cap \im(\beta))=0$

Answer (score 2):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\image}{im}$
**Hint:** Let $n = \dim(V)$.
Since $\image(\alpha) + \image(\beta) = V$, we may state that:

- $\dim(\image(\alpha)) + \dim(\ker(\alpha)) = n$
- $\dim(\image(\beta)) + \dim(\ker(\beta)) = n$
- $\dim(\image(\alpha)) + \dim(\image(\beta)) \geq n$
- $\dim(\ker(\alpha)) + \dim(\ker(\beta)) \geq n$

You can use this to conclude that 
$$
\dim(\ker(\alpha)) + \dim(\ker(\beta)) = \dim(\image(\beta)) + \dim(\ker(\beta)) = n
$$
from which you may directly deduce the desired conclusion by noting that for subspaces $A,B \subset V$, we have
$$
\dim(A + B) \leq \dim(A) + \dim(B)
$$
with equality if and only if $A \cap B = \{\vec 0\}$.